# Chrome profile snapshot & timeline updated documentation

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, performancecounter

I very keen on learning how chrome devtools works, particularly the Profile and Timeline feature as I am investigating some excessive memory consume of a web app.
I have read the following documentation:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling

both of them seems out-dated.
Is there any place to request or see up-to-date documentation about this topics?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So far my best finding is: http://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated documentation is here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/